# Specific API or localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, cordova, local-storage

I'm developing a client application for a customer's webservice with Angular and Cordova.

The `Login` API returns an array of categories I have to use in the menù.

My question is, if I want to keep good design or performances:
do I ask them to write an API to fetch the categories of the menù anytime I want
or on Login success I store them into the localStorage ?

is it more expensive to keep making API calls or instantiate a localStorage ?

Answer (score 1):

If the menu items don't change too often you should fetch them from the server as rarely as possible to prevent using network (I'm assuming we're taliking about some mobile platform, cf. Cordova).

Polling is expensive : for network resources obviously, but also for battery life. If you think the menu items won't change between two logins, then fetch it once and store it.

And same goes with most of the infos you think won't change very often. Avoid polling the server (and think about offline mode and stuff like that). You should always be thinking about how often data changes and store as many things as possible.

If some data can change and you can't avoid polling from the server, think about a good API design : like [conditionnal requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/#conditional-requests) for instance, to avoid unnecessary network traffic and parsing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I assume retrieving categories will be possible to be the first of a list of services that your App will consume in the future. For escalability and performance reasons retrieving a Auth token on login and retrieving the last time categories have changed and calling for categories if changes exists could be a middle design approach with the cost of an extra service.